# Steiner Tree Problem for n=3

Tags: geometry

Shortest distance between the vertices of a right angle triangle. The length of the sides of the triangle are in the ratio 3:4:5.

In other words, solution to Steiner Tree Problem for n=3 for points X, Y and Z which, when connected, form the above mentioned triangle.

Answer (score 0):

On the outside of the triangle erect equilateral triangles $XYA$ and $YZB$. The circumcircles of $XYA$ and $YZB$ intersect at $Y$ and at another point $W$. And we have $\angle XWY=\angle ZWY=\angle XWZ=2\pi /3$.

So $W$ is the Steiner point of $A,B,C$.  The minimum length of a spanning tree for $X,Y,Z$ is $XW+YW+ZW.$

Comment: Why does $\angle XWY=\angle ZWY=\angle XWZ=2\pi /3$ imply that $W$ is the Steiner point?

Comment: Because that is Steiner's Theorem : See  Steiner Tree Problem . Also Fermat Point.

Answer (score 0):

**Statement.** *Point $W$ satisfies the property $WV = WX + WY$ if and only if $W$ lies on the circumcircle $k$ of the equilateral triangle $XYV$, on the arc between points $X$ and $Y$ not containing $V$.*

[image]

*Proof:* Assume that $W$ is a point on the plane so that $WV$ is larger than both $WX$ and $WY$. Then perform a $60^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise rotation around the point $A$ and let $W^*$ be the image of $W$ under the rotation.  Then $WV=W^*V$ and $\angle \, WVW^* = 60^{\circ}$. Hence triangle $WVW^*$ is equilateral and $WV=W^*V = WW^*$. Moreover, since triangle $XYV$ is equilateral itself, point $X$ is the image of point $Y$ under the counter-clockwise $60^{\circ}$ rotation. Consequently, triangle $VXW^*$ is the rotation image of $VYW$ and so these two triangles are congruent. Thus, $WY=W^*X$.

Observe that triangle $WXW^*$ is a triangle with edges $WW^* = WV, \,\, W^*X = WY$ and $WX$.

Now, assume first that $WV = WX + WY$. Then $WW^* = WX + W^*X$ which is possible if and only if $X$ lies on the edge $WW^*$. But then $\angle \, XWV = \angle \, W^*WV = 60^{\circ}$ because $W^*VW$ is equilateral. Consequently $\angle\, XWV = \angle \, XYV = 60^{\circ}$ which means that point $P$ lies on the circumcircle $k$ of triangle $XYZ$.

Conversely, let $W$ be on the circumcircle $k$ of the equilateral triangle $XYZ$. Then $\angle\, XWV = \angle \, XYV = 60^{\circ}$. On the other hand by construction triangle $W^*WV$ is equilateral so $60^{\circ} = \angle \, W^*WV = \angle CPA$ which is possible if and only if point $X$ lies on the segment $W^*W$ (here is where we use the condition that $P$ is located on the arc $XY$ disjoint form $V$ which guarantees that $X$ and $W^*$ are on the same side of line $VW$). But then, $WW^* = W^*X + WX$ and since it has already been established that $WW^* = WV$ and $W^*X = WY$, we conclude that $WV = WX + WY$.

$$ $$

To construct the point $W$, construct equilateral triangle $XYV$ on the side $XY$ of triangle $XYZ$ outside $XYZ$ ant draw its circumcircle $k$. The intersection $W$ of $k$ with $ZV$ is the point with the property that $$WX+WY+WZ = WV + WZ = ZV$$ which is a stright segment and that's why it is the shortest distance between $Z$ and $W$. Hence the minimum of the sum $WX+WY+WZ$.

[image]